# Can I make Tomcat 7 to deploy the configured webapps but not to start them?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, tomcat7

I'm doing some deploy / start / stop tests locally on my computer, and it would be very comfortable to have my webapps deployed (so they can be managed throught the Tomcat manager webapp) but not started right away when Tomcat start.

Is this feasible at all?

Within the documentation I only found how to deploy or not deploy a webapp at all (through the "Host" configuration in `server.xml`).

This is a portion of my `server.xml`:

```
  <Host name="host1.localpc"  appBase="C:\tools\tomcat\webapps\host1" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployIgnore="^(?!ROOT$).*?$" deployOnStartup="true">
    <Context docBase="C:\tools\tomcat\runnable\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\manager" path="/manager" privileged="true" />
  </Host>
  <Host name="host2.localpc"  appBase="C:\tools\tomcat\webapps\host2" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployIgnore="^(?!ROOT$).*?$" deployOnStartup="true">
    <Context docBase="C:\tools\tomcat\runnable\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\manager" path="/manager" privileged="true" />
  </Host>
  <Host name="host3.localpc"  appBase="C:\tools\tomcat\webapps\host3" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployIgnore="^(?!ROOT$).*?$" deployOnStartup="true">
    <Context docBase="C:\tools\tomcat\runnable\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\manager" path="/manager" privileged="true" />
  </Host>
```

Hostnames are handled throught the Windows HOSTS file.
I'm running Tomcat 7.0.69

Answer (score 0):

Hum... Certainly, as far as I know, any war is automatically started by Tomcat just after being deployed. Still, I'd suggest you to take a look at the [Tomcat Client Deployer](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_using_the_Tomcat_Manager), a module from which you can get an Ant script to deploy-and-stop your application. To accomplish this, you should:

- [Download the TCD](http://ftp.cixug.es/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.77/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.77-deployer.zip).
- Parametrize the `build.xml`.
- Invoke `ant deploy stop` to deploy and stop.